# How to see index.htm from local directories in internet browser?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, html

I have a folder full of websites with an **index.htm** in that folder linking to each one.

When I type the file path to that folder into **google chrome**, it opens the folder as if looking at the index of a file server that has no **index.htm** page.

Only, I *do* have an **index.htm**. So, is there a way to make it so that browsers will open the **index.htm** when given the path to that folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are using a webserver, which can be configured to perform default document substitution, you cannot use just the parent directory path to access the file. you will have to put in the full path, ending in index.htm.

The use of index.htm or default.htm is just convention; it is not standard, so the browser does not try to infer possible default documents. only the server can make that decision, so don't try to open the folder, try to open the file.

`file://path/to/file/index.htm`

Answer (score 2):

You can use C:/path to folder/index.htm

if you only use folder path browser will only display folder, if you really want this to load a page by default you can use a local server using [Wamp server](http://www.wampserver.com/)

The setup is also explained on the site.